# Convert this C# code in geometry nodes for a volume grid

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make fractals with the Volume cube in 3.3 geometry nodes. I've found this distance estimated fractal equation in C#.

```
float DE(vec3 z)
{
    vec3 a1 = vec3(1,1,1);
    vec3 a2 = vec3(-1,-1,1);
    vec3 a3 = vec3(1,-1,-1);
    vec3 a4 = vec3(-1,1,-1);
    vec3 c;
    int n = 0;
    float dist, d;
    while (n < Iterations) {
         c = a1; dist = length(z-a1);
         d = length(z-a2); if (d < dist) { c = a2; dist=d; }
         d = length(z-a3); if (d < dist) { c = a3; dist=d; }
         d = length(z-a4); if (d < dist) { c = a4; dist=d; }
        z = Scale*z-c*(Scale-1.0);
        n++;
    }

    return length(z) * pow(Scale, float(-n));
}
```

But the end result is... well nothing. Just a rounded cube. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 3D version of the famous fractal:

[image]

[image]

Nodes inside:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're the real Blender Guru my guy.